# What is the context-free grammar for $0^{n}1^{2n+1}0^{n}$

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar

context free grammar for $0^{n}1^{2n+1}0^{n}$

I've tried several different methods to find it but I can't figure out how to make both sides opposite to each other...please help I've been working on this for hours.

Comment: Does the question say that it *definitely is* a CFG? If not, is it possible that you're supposed to use the pumping lemma to show that it isn't a CFG?

Comment: No the question is specifically: Find a Context-Free Grammar that generates and a Pushdown Automaton that accepts the
language $0^{n}1^{2n+1}0^{n}$. Prove their correctness.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to prove that this language is not a CFG using the [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages).

Proof sketch

> The pumping lemma states that $\exists$ p such that all strings s : |s| > p contain "pumpable" constituents so that s = uvwxy so that 
>     1) |vwx| $\le $ p 
>     2) |vx| $\ge$ 1 
>     3) uv$^k$wx$^k$y  is a valid string in the language for all k 
>  Consider the string s = $0^p 1^p 1 1^p 0^p$. Clearly |s| > p and s is in the language 
>  Claim 1: The string vx must have equal number of 0 and 1, and neither u nor y should contain p zeros. otherwise 3) would be violated 
>  Claim 2: If vx contain equal number of 0 and 1 in total then its impossible that |vwx| $\le$ p 
>  Claim 1 and Claim 2 prove that its impossible to find "pumpable" uvwxy for string s which has length greater than p. which violates the pumping lemma.

Comment: The question asks for a CFG and a PDA specifically, and for us to prove that they work. I found a PDA for it already, just can't get the CFG...yes I've tried conversion methods.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post rules for the PDA? I think that my argument that the language violates the pumping lemma is correct but its not impossible that I am wrong.

Comment: what do you mean by rules? like how it works? i used 3 stacks...i'm not sure if that's allowed

Comment: @MikailaHirschler A PDA with just two stacks is as expressive as a Turing machine, so no, it's not allowed.

Comment: Yeah I meant the functions that you use for the transition or the construction. Actually even 2 stacks make the machine as powerful as a TM. I am not an expert but look at the following which seems to suggest that using 3 stacks is cheating: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/is-a-push-down-automaton-with-two-stacks-equivalent-to-a-turing-machine

Comment: what if i'm switching the symbols in a transition...for example i have 1: Y -> Z